# Need Help bootstrap Nested Grid 4 column 3 left 1 right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a contact page but can't make the third column in the current place. Please see the image I have attached. I need exactly [4 Columns - 3 left 1 right Bootstrap grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwY3O.png)

Example what I am trying to do:

```
<div class="contact-border col-xs-11">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-9">
 <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">Address
</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">Icon</td>
        <td valign="middle">Phone</td>
      </tr>
<tr>
<td align="left">Icon</td>
<td>email</td>
</tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <ul class="social-network social-circle">
                      Social Icons
                    </ul>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
Contact Form
    </div>
</div>
</div>
....................
. 1 . 2 .          .
. .......     4    .
.       .          .
.   3   .          .
....................
```

Comment: Can you show your attempt at the markup please?

Comment: George thank you reply. Just problem just solved by Andy. Thanks again for your concern. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it using bootstraps grid system

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
            1
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
            2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
            4
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
    3
    </div>
</div>
```

Add this to your css to make the right column (3) equal heigh as your left column (1,2,4)

```
.row {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display:         flex;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I am new in bootstrap so just learning and thanks for the help it helped me a lot :) best wishes